# How to alert React-JS fetch values

Tags: json, reactjs, webapi

I have a Web API that takes 3 parameters (e.g: int EID, string MUN, string MUP) and then return a JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "MemberID": 71,
        "MemberExamID": 1
    }
]
```

Now I want to alert 'MemberID' in my React-JS project, when the user click on 'Submit' button.
and this is part of my React-JS codes too:

```
export class LoginModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { MemberID: 0}
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API + 'MemberExamValidation', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                EID: event.target.ExamID.value,
                MUN: event.target.EDT_Username.value,
                MUP: event.target.EDT_Password.value
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ MemberID: data.MemberID });
            alert(this.state.MemberID);
         },
         (error) => {
             alert('Erroe');
         })
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the syntax is wrong? You should write the Promise like this --> https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-forest-ymzf7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When I press Submit button, it say Undefine

Answer (score 0):

The the `setState` function is async which means if you try to read the value right after you set it, it'll not work the way you've done it. Instead try this -

```
this.setState({
  MemberID: data.MemberID,
}, () => {
  // read value here
  alert(this.state.MemberID)
});
```

Read more about setState callback here - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: There can be issue in your code. Have a look at Codesandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-flower-czk25?file=/src/App.js